Chrome Extension (v3) - Download a Uint8array file (.ts file)
I have a Uint8array (that I've created by concatenating arrayBuffers from fetching several .ts files); I am attempting to send the U8A as a message to a content script in a tab and download it by creating a virtual A element with a filename/url (URL.createObjectURL method and download="filename.extension"). However, even this is not working; any suggestions?
I've tried downloading using chrome.downloads.download({url,filename});
(with a url of arrayBuffer/uint8array/blob)
URL.createObjectURL cannot be used in a serviceWorker FYI.
and sending the uint8array to a CS as a message is also unsuccessful (for unknown reasons).
I've also tried converting the uint8array to base64, however this method crashed the browser (the file(s) are 1gb min to 3gb max).

Use the offscreen document, example.

Another solution is a web_accessible_resources iframe, example.
